# How to find time difference in milliseconds from two datetime stamp field using ruby

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I need to get time difference from two time stamp fields,
i.e.,
My input :
 "requestTime" => "2016-12-27 18:35:13:833",
 "responseTime" => "2016-12-27 18:35:13:834",

I Need to get time diff as 1 milliseconds as a result.

I used this code :

```
 event['time_difference']= (Time.parse(event['responseTime']).to_i) - (Time.parse(event['requestTime']).to_i)
```

I got result as 0 seconds for above input.

Comment: How it will be duplicate, its about the time format time to millisecond before applying the difference.

There, it was said like apply the difference and convert the seconds to millisecond. i thing both have some difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `to_f`

```
millisec = 1000 * (response_time.to_f - request_time.to_f)
```

The timestamps must have this format though,

```
"2016-12-27 18:35:13.833"
```

Notice the `.` separator between seconds and milliseconds!

Comment: Yes, separator between the seconds and milliseconds is the problem, Thanks @akuhn

Comment: If we need to store this in a specific column in rails, what would be the apt column type?